# Callbacks in views

Tags: backbone.js

This may be more of a question around design pattern - I hope it makes sense.

I am using backbone - am developing a relatively simple app where user can add requests (where the request model is simply heading, description and price).  The only requirement to add the requests is that a user is 'logged in'.

However I wish that the user 'adds' the request before checking if the user is logged in (remove one barrier).  By that I mean that the user fills the form in, if not registered they have to register and then the request is just sent, if they were logged in it would just be sent.  So initially the 'add request' view is rendered, when save is triggered this will call the save on the model which calls the ajax request on the server.  The response will either return true (the user was logged in and the request added) or false (the user was not logged in).

So assuming that the user was not logged in - then I would wish to render a new view 'register' which has the option for the user to switch to 'login' (another view). So User in theory could go from

```
Request (save)  -> Register -> Login -> Request (save)
```

So presuming that the user then registered (filled in the form which then called the registers view save method which then called the registers model save and returned ok).  I would then wish to once again call the 'request' save method once again (as now the user would be logged in).  However I do not want the register/login tied to the Request view - as in theory a new view (lets say I had a sent message view) would want similar functionality e.g. try and make the request, if failed switch view to register - perform save and then call some callback.

So the question is what is the right way to do this?

1)  Do I create some closure inside the request view referencing the 'save' function and store it in a global to be called by register/login onsuccess?
2)  Create a closure as above and pass that to the register etc (and if so how would I pass this given register/login is a view).
3)  Pass a reference to 'this' of the request view?

So far all I have is, so in the else I would render the 'register' view but would love to know best way to do this without it getting very ugly?

```
save : function(event){
    if(this.model.isValid() == true) {
        this.$("#general_error").hide();
        this.model.set({'formattedPrice' : TB_H.formatPrice(this.model.get('currency'), this.model.get('price'))});
        self = this;
        this.model.save(this.model.toJSON(), {
                success: function(m, y) {
                    if(y.status == true) {
                        self.model = new TB_BB.Request(); 
                        Backbone.ModelBinding.bind(self);           
                        Backbone.Validation.bind(self);
                        $('#add-offer-button').show();
                    } else {                            
                        if(y.errors[0] == 'not logged in') {
                            this.$("#general_error").html('You are not logged in');
                            this.$("#general_error").show();                                
                        } else {                            
                            _.each(y.errors, function(key, val) { this.$("#general_error").html(key) });
                            this.$("#general_error").show();
                        }

                    }
                }, error : function(m,y) { 
                    this.$("#general_error").show();
                    this.$("#general_error").html("Something bad happened - please try again")
                }
            }
        );

    }
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: How did you end up working through this? I'm encountering something similar myself

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this after asking a similar question, which I just deleted. I'm thinking this isn't the way most people are doing it in backbone.

what I did instead was pass my different routes to the same method and if the ids were not null, I'd call the route.

So I have a view

```
base_view = Backbone.Views.extend({
    initialize: function(id,a_id,b_id){
       this.id = id;
       this.a_id = a_id;
       this.b_id = b_id;
       Myapp.data = new Myapp.Model.Base();
       Myapp.data.url = '/data_url/'+id;
       Myapp.data.fetch(Myapp.data, {
              success: function(response){
               // i have some nested collections, and models so i fill those in here
               Myapp.mainModel = new First_Child_Collection(response.attributes.first_child_array);
          },  error: function(){
              alert('oops couldn't get data');
          }
    });
  Myapp.data.bind("fetched",this.render,this);
},

  render: function(){
      new Main_View();
      new Sub_View_1(this.id);
      new Sub_View_2(this.a_id);
      new Sub_View_3(this.b_id);
  }
});
```

Then in my routes, rather than having a new route for each, I have

```
routes: {
        "app/new":  "new",
        "app/:id/edit/a/:a_id/b/:b_id": "edit"

}

edit {
     new base_view(id,a_id,b_id);

}
```

I'm not sure if this is perfect, but I think it is DRY'r than the other options. I just check that a_id or b_id are not undefined before passing those views.

Hope it helps.